# MySQL DB Structure - Scheduling System

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, structure

Working on a project where people can schedule and locate games for their teams and I'm looking for input on the DB structure. Below is something I had in mind:

```
table: Teams
col: id | name | age | birth_year | zip

table: Games
col: id | team_one_id | team_two_id | team_one_score | team_two_score | date | time
```

When a user posts a game as available their 'id' will go in 'team_one_id' and 'team_two_id' will be NULL until a game is accepted by an opponent. The issue is that in order for me to get all games tied to 'Team A' is to search both 'team_one_id' and 'team_two_id' columns.

Should I add another table like the one below:

```
table: teamGames
col: team_id | game_id
```

There will be two entries for each game ( one for each team ). Would this help speed up my queries? Hopefully all this is somewhat understandable.

Comment: Side notes: `age` depends on `birth_year` and will change over time. It shouldn't be materialized, drop that column. The columns `date` and `time` are probably better fused together.

Comment: Another Advantage of a linking table between games and teams would also be that it can be easily adapted for games with more than two teams. You forgot however, that the score should also be moved to that table.

Comment: As I see, it is simple many to many relation between Team and Game, just write some business logic to prevent same Team twise in one Game

Comment: Imagine giving birth to a team. More generally, there are thousands of examples of similar schema out there so I'd be tempted to look at those

Answer (score 0):

```
Game            pivot            Team
-id             -game_id         -id
-date           -team_id         -name
-time                            ...
```

Write logic in php: one Game has two teams (in pivot can't be more then 2 records for the same Game)